# Determine if the intersection of two surfaces is a non-singular curve

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Let $S_1$, $S_2$ be two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ implicitly defined by, respectively, $f_1(x,y,z)=0$ and $f_2(x,y,z)=0$. How do I check if the curve $S_1 \cap S_2$ has singular points without explicitly deriving a parametrization? Example:

$$S_1 = \{x^3 + 3(y^2+z^2)^2=2\} \\ S_2 = \{x^4 = y^3\}$$

I see no obvious way for a parametrization of $S_1 \cap S_2$, so how do I go about checking if it has singular points?

And, as a bonus more general question: in situations like this, how much information about the intersection curve can I derive just by looking at the surfaces?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down the Jacobian matrix 
$$
\big{(}\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\big{)}.
$$
A point will be singular iff the Jacobian matrix doesn't have full rank.

In this case, the matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3x^2 & 6y(y^2+z^2) & 6z(y^2+z^2) \\
4x^3 & -3y^2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Let's say $x = 0$. Then this matrix will fail to have full rank if $18y^2z(y^2+z^2) = 0$, i.e. if $y$ or $z$ is $0$. Staring at the equations for a minute, we see that  the two points $(0, 0, \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac{2}{3}}$) will be singular points.

If $x \neq 0$, then column 3 is linearly independent of column $1$ unless $z = 0$. In that case, column 2 is $\begin{pmatrix} 6y^3 \\ -3y^2 \end{pmatrix}$, and so there could be a singular point where $-9x^2 -24x^3y^3 = 0,$ i.e. where $3+8xy^3 = 0$. Such a point is on $S_2$ iff $3 + 8x^5 = 0$, i.e. $x = \sqrt[5]{-\frac{3}{8}}$. Now we can solve for $y$ and see that such a point isn't on $S_1$, so there's no other singular points beyond the two we already found.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\nabla f_2(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{
\partial}{\partial x}f_1(x,y,z),
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_1(x,y,z),
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_1(x,y,z) 
\right)$ is normal to $S_1$ and $\nabla f_2(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{
\partial}{\partial x}f_2(x,y,z),
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_2(x,y,z),
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f_2(x,y,z) 
\right) $ is normal to $S_2$. The vectorial product $\nabla f_1(x,y,z)\times \nabla f_1(x,y,z)$  is a multiple of the vector tangent to the curve $S_1\cap S_2$.